# <li> elements must be contained in a <ul> or <ol> in Stenciljs

Tags: stenciljs

I am trying to implement the following in an accessible manner:

```
<ul>
  <my-li>
    #shadow-root
    <li>
      <span>hello!</span>
    </li>
  </my-li>
</ul>
```

In Stenciljs classes decorated with @Component can not extend from a base class, therefore this method of [customizing built-in elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements#customized_built-in_elements) is not applicable here.

Is there any way to set the type of a HTMLElement that is a Stenciljs component?

Comment: I don't see how you're going to get around this. Maybe you can get your `my-li` to function as an `li`? instead of needing a nested one?

Comment: @user207421 thank you for the response. You could do that but the question is whether it is possible to set the type of a HTMLElement that is a Stenciljs component. So the answer is you can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It is an HTML restriction.

You could replace your whole `<my-li>` Web Component with its content:

```js
customElements.define("my-li",class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"}); // for demo, just showing shadowRoot is replaced
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    this.parent = this.parentNode;
    setTimeout(() => { // only if you need its innerHTML (and do not have a large DOM inside!)
      this.replaceWith(
        Object.assign(
          document.createElement("LI") , {
            id        : this.id,
            innerHTML : this.innerHTML
          }));
    });
  }
  disconnectedCallback(){
    console.log(this.parent.outerHTML);
  }
})
```

```html
<ul>
 <my-li id="FOO"><b>BAR</b></my-li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking you can do this with a Stencil component (version 2.11.0 at least), but I'm not sure it would be useful.

```
import { Component, Element } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
    tag: 'my-li',
    shadow: true
})
export class MyLi {

    @Element() hostElement;

    render() {
        this.hostElement.outerHTML = `
            <li>
                <span>hello!</span>
            </li>
        `;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that you won't actually see the component in DOM at all - it's replaced by the `<li>`:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>hello!</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is why the usefulness is questionable - you can't manipulate the component after it's in the DOM through properties or methods as you could an actual component, and you can't listen to or emit events.

You can, however, at least use properties to initialize the content:

```
...
@Prop() label: string = 'label';

render() {
    this.hostElement.outerHTML = `
        <li>
            <span>${this.label}</span>
        </li>
    `;
    return null;
}
```